# Unable to pass a parent component's state to its child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I cannot pass a parent's state to its child component.

I've tried passing the whole parent's state to the child, however, the content of the state itself was `undefined`.
Also, I've tried similarly by using props, but it did not work well either.

---

```
//parent.js

state = {
  messages: [],
  roomId: this.props.navigation.getParam('roomId')
}

renderImageAction = () => {
  return <ImageAction roomId={this.state.roomId} />
}

return(<GiftedChat renderActions={this.renderImageAction}/>)
```

---

```
//child.js
DataBase.saveImage(this.props.roomId).then(alert('done'));
```

I expect that the state or the value will be passed to the child component, and there the value will be available.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to understand this thing to my perspective. Hope this helps.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

      fieldVal: ""

    }

  }

  onUpdate = (val) => {

    this.setState({

      fieldVal: val

    })

  };

  render() {

    return (

      <div>

        <h2>Parent</h2>

        Value in Parent Component State: {this.state.fieldVal}

        <br/>

        <Child onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />

        <br />

        <OtherChild passedVal={this.state.fieldVal} />

      </div>

    )

  }

}



class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

      fieldVal: ""

    }

  }

  update = (e) => {

    console.log(e.target.value);

    this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);

    this.setState({fieldVal: e.target.value});

  };

  render() {

    return (

      <div>

        <h4>Child</h4>

        <input

          type="text"

          placeholder="type here"

          onChange={this.update}

          value={this.state.fieldVal}

        />

      </div>

    )

  }

}

class OtherChild extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div>

        <h4>OtherChild</h4>

        Value in OtherChild Props: {this.props.passedVal}

      </div>

    )

  }

}

React.render(

  <Parent />,

  document.getElementById('react_example')

);
```